# High quality/performance shared hosting (in northern Europe)

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I work as a web developer on almost all levels. However, my typical customer is a 1-5 guys running some sort of consulting business. They have (or want) a web page with some kind of CMS so the can perform most (or all) editing themselves. I normally opt for Concrete5 as my default CMS because it's the most user friendly (and free) CMS I have found.

My good recurring customers I host on my own server as a service, but I need a good host for the customers where I want to deliver a product and not be responsible for whatever may happen in the future. However, I still struggle with hosting! Experience shows that the typical ~1$ shared hosting is waaay to slow to run concrete5 smoothly, and a VPS is out of the question because I don't want to maintain it.

So, where can I find as fast (from northern Europe), reliable, shared host where I can put a site and don't have to worry about the server going down or being unmaintained.

I expect this should cost around $10-$20 but I'm open to all kinds of suggestions because different customers have different budgets.

Answer (score 1):

I've been satisfied with [WebFaction](http://webfaction.com)(registered in England and Wales) for a while now. I moved a client's WordPress site that was bringing a MediaTemple grid account to a crawl over there, and it's never even stuttered.

**EDIT 06.28**: WebFaction have just [announced](http://blog.webfaction.com/2011/06/europe-here-we-come/) European servers(London).

Comment: I am using WebFaction as well and I can really recommend it. There is just one slight problem: all its servers are based in the US...

Comment: @Su': I think it's worth noting that WebFaction DOES NOT PROVIDE CPANEL, but their own made control panel. I have nothing against this, but whoever buy their service and one day needs to go away it might find himself stuck!!! Instead whenever you buy a cPanel based hosting you can always move away to another cPanel hoster with almost no pain, so as a customer you have definietly more bargaining power!

Comment: @Su': and there are people already compaling about this aspect of not provideing cPanel: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=956742&highlight=Webfaction I know just one review on WHT doesn't mean anything, that's why I suggested in my question to always search for reviews in the WHT forum.

Comment: @Marco Demaio I don't think I see your point. It's not as if CPanel is standard, nor was it a requirement of the question. (I can't even remember the last time I had a hosting account with it, for that matter.) While a couple people in that WHT thread made note of the custom panel, I would not describe anyone as *complaining*. Plenty of hosts have custom interfaces. I have no idea what you're talking about that the lack of CPanel might leave someone "stuck" if they want to switch hosts.

Comment: @Su': I didn't want to make any point, or criticize your answer, I was just warning out that they do not provide cPanel. And as I said "I have nothing against this". Remaining 'stuck' was maybe a too strong word, I meant it's obviously easier to swicth between hosts that both provide cPanel, and due to the fact that the vast majority pof hoster provide cPanel I think the final customer has more bargaining power.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Eco Web Hosting](http://www.ecowebhosting.co.uk/). I've not had any problems at all running Concrete5 on their servers. The only major problem I've found is there web interace for account management is pretty horrific, but once you are set up there are no problems. It's UK based and aims to be Carbon Neutral.

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to http://www.ezpzhosting.co.uk/

or http://www.eukhost.com/

**But you better always check 1st on WebHsotingTalk** [searching the Main Webhosting Forum](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/search.php) for keywords containing the hoster name like: "ezpz review", "eukhost"

The eukhost is extermely cheap, an probably you get what you pay for, many bad reviews on WHT, [even on their forum](http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f13/avoid-eukhost-like-plague-14901/) :-), but I have to say I somehow appreciate they are so transaparent, not many hosters would do the same.
Moreover I used their almost cheapest hosting (Linux Bornze) in my experince wasn't great, but for the ridicolous price I paid I probably can not complain, and maybe more expensive plans like VPS are more reliable.

Finally **always ask technical pre-sales questions to get at least a feeling of their know how**.